# AndroidManifest.xml could not be found

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-manifest

I am taking a flutter course, and i have downloaded the resources of the course to run it in my device,
but there is an error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml could not be found.
Please check C:\Users\manal\Downloads\state-02-detail-screen\android\AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyi0X.jpg)

as shown in the picture, in other flutter projects, in top left, there is always item called 'Android' under list of project, but here it doesn't appear

Comment: "Consider running "flutter create ." to create one."

Comment: flutter create what?
and i write it in the terminal, righr?

Answer (score 2):

As the instructions say, run

```
flutter create .
```

Comment: in flutter 4, ai can fix problems like this

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of the old version, delete the SDK flutter and download the new version and the problem will go away

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).